# ORA-06413: Connection not open, works fine on my other pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g

I am currently getting an error "ORA-06413: Connection not open." in one of my asp.net web applications, I am currently using Visual Studio 2010, I have Windows 7 (64-bit) installed, with the oracle 10g (10.3) client installed.

Now the reason I am asking the community is that I have 2 pc's that I develop on, they are both the exact same spec, using the exact same software, only the one that currently does not give me this error was installed six months ago, and the PC that is giving me the error is a newly installed PC.

The code runs fine on the one pc anad generates an error on the other pc:

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=!!!HOSTNAME!!!)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = dwh)(SRVR = DEDICATED)));User ID=user;Password=pass;");
        con.Open();
        string sql = "select * "
           + "from ods_dw.base";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

However, on the newly installed PC ( 1 of 6 new pc's) I get this error. TOAD however has no problem connecting to the database. So could someone please advise me on what to check for and what I could be missing?

Comment: If you google this error, they mention this error is caused by an illegal character in the path of the executable - have you verified this is not the case? (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06413_connection_not_open.htm)

Comment: Whats the path for your `TOAD` installation, i think something to do with (x86) in path names of the 64 bit machines, check on those lines. [some hints](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/ab662d63-6385-4f73-b27f-d526048f601f/)

Comment: I have googled this error, I have actually formatted and re-installed the entire operating system, I made sure to install everything to the program files folder and not the the (x86) folder. I have also created the project on the c:\ in a folder called work, this way I have gotten rid of any chance of parentheses. What gets me is that I did not follow any of these steps in the other 5 pc that I have installed and they are all working correctly.

Comment: @V4Vendetta strangly enough, the pc's that are working I have TOAD in the (x86) folder, and it works with no issues, it is just the one machine (wich I have replaced with a new machine) that is giving me this error.

Comment: What line exactly generates this error? What is the stack trace?

Comment: the error is generated at the con.Open(); I don't have the stack trace at the moment as I am not at the office, will post it tomorrow if I am still having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was:

First, ensure (manually) the libraries of the OracleClient in the work station.

I have created folders in this way:
C:\Oracle
C:\Oracle\Bin
C:\Oracle\Network\Admin

Is not necessary any folder more.
The folders in this step are empty.

**Ensure enviroment variables**

```
PATH:           Must include oracle bin path: C:\Oracle\Bin\
ORACLE_HOME:    C:\Oracle
TNS_ADMIN:      C:\Oracle\Network\Admin
NLS_LANG:       American_America.UTF8 (or find the righ value if is necessary)

JAVA_HOME:      (install java normally to get this configuration)
```

**Ensure Windows Registry entries**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_Oracle]
"StmtCacheSize"="0"
"ORACLE_HOME_NAME"="Oracle"
"ORACLE_BASE"="C:\\Oracle\\"
"VERSION"="10.2.0.1.0"
@=""
"ORACLE_HOME_KEY"="SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_Oracle"
"NLS_LANG"="LATIN AMERICAN SPANISH_COLOMBIA.WE8MSWIN1252"
"ORAMTS_CP_TRACE_LEVEL"="0"
"ORACLE_HOME"="C:\\Oracle\\"
"ORAMTS_CP_TRACE_DIR"="C:\\Oracle\\oramts\\trace"
"StatementCacheSize"="0"
"OLEDB"="C:\\Oracle\\oledb\\mesg"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_Oracle\ODP.NET]
"TraceFileName"="C:\\Oracle\\ODPNET.trc"
"TraceLevel"="0"
"TraceOption"="0"
"StatementCacheSize"="10"
@=""
"Version"="10.2.0.100"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_Oracle\OLEDB]
"CacheType"="Memory"
"ChunkSize"="100"
"DistribTX"="1"
"FetchSize"="100"
"OSAuthent"="0"
"PLSQLRset"="0"
"PwdChgDlg"="1"
"SchRstLng"="10000"
"UserDefFn"="0"
"DisableRetClause"="1"
"VCharNull"="1"
"TraceCategory"="0"
"TraceFileName"="c:\\Oracle\\OraOLEDB.trc"
"TraceLevel"="0"
"TraceOption"="0"
"SPPrmDefVal"="0"
"StmtCacheSize"="10"
@=""
```

It's possible that these entries may not all be required but I had not time to check each one.

**NEXT STEP**
I have created a Console App to test connection. This must include System.Data.OracleClient reference.

The C:\Oracle\Bin folder in my first test was empty. No libraries yet.
But TNSNAMES.ora must exist in the folder C:\Oracle\Network\Admin
with alias targeting to oracle instance.

Ovbiously, is necessary ensure that other client connect to the instance, like SQLPLUS, Toad or many others. Or at least ensure connection from workstation to instance server through the port of the instance, by default is: 1521

My basic code

```
using System;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace ConsoleApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            try {
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=myuser; Password=mypwd; Data Source=MYSSID")) {
                    conn.Open();
                }//End using
                Console.WriteLine("CONECTION SUCCESS!");
            }//End try
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + ex.Message);
            }//End catch

        Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Is possible that this return a message saying something like Oracle requires minimum version xx to connect, this is because the bin directory is empty.

So next I had downloaded most old libraries from de oracle page
In this moment from here:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

And I had start to put each one in Bin folder and try connection until one of these get success connection.

Next, I did same thing with a Web Application, but in this case is necessary close IIS express server each time to change libraries.

In my case, it works with this libraries:
instantclient-basiclite-win32-10.2.0.5

In both, web application and console application
Other libraries only works with console application

Please leave comments if you need additional information to help to fix this problem.

I know this post is too old, but I needed to connect to Oracle 9i at the moment and I did not find any solution. If someone else had the same problem, I hope this is helpful.

Don't forget that on IIS (not express) is necessary change process to 32-Bit architecture

Comment: In addition, is necessary to setup 32-Bit application en IIS.

In IIS10 go to:
ApplicationPool -> AdvancedSettings -> Enable 32-Bit Applications -> TRUE

It fix this error: "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."